# What does the following phrase mean “扈江离与辟芷兮，纫秋兰以为佩.”?

Tags: mandarin, traditional-characters, classical-chinese, phrase

I think its a line written by the poet Qu Yuan that maybe symbolizes a persons nobility?

Answer (score 1):

From 屈原《离骚》( 'Lisao' by Qu Yuan)

扈(to wear/to carry) | 江篱(a kind of fragrant plant) | 与(and) | 辟芷(a kind of fragrant plant) | 兮(exclamatory particle)

纫(to sew) | 秋兰 (a kind of fragrant plant) | 以为 (to make) | 佩 (sachet)

扈江篱与辟芷兮，纫秋兰以为佩

"Wear verrucosa and angelica dahurica , sew a sachet with autumn orchid inside"

```
maybe symbolizes a persons nobility?
```

This line symbolizes Qu Yuan's high moral standards, and his unwillingness of associate with immoral people.

(*bad guys stink*)

Answer (score 0):

善鸟香草以配忠贞。凸现屈原高尚品德，不与世俗同流合污的高尚情操。

This famous idiom comes from QuYuan's works called "LiSao", which was a collection of poets written by him.

The original meaning of the statement is: I put on Cao Zhi around my shoulders, and tied QiuLan to Sope to hang it beside myself.

For Chinese, the plants of "QuiLan" or "Cao Zhi" are of self-contained, so QuYuan used these plants to describe that His passion/sentiment for people, for the motherland is so high that he wasn't willing to associate himself with undesirable elements.